# promises and deferred in ajax and jquery

Tags: promise, jquery-deferred

This is a sample functionality I need, is it possible??. I am facing problem in debugging it
I need those two functions to be ran before I do any other modification how to do it?

```
function getPromise() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();


    $.when(getPromiseother()).done(function() {
        deferred.resolve();
    });

    deferred.getPromiseother()
}

function getPromise() {
    var deferrednext = $.Deferred();


    $.when($.ajax(somefunction)).done(function() {
        deferrednext.resolve();
    });

    deferrednext.promise()
}
$.when(getPromise).done(function() {
    do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very clumsy way to do this - basically a major point of promises is that they compose and chain and you don't need to `$.Deferred` anywhere that's not converting a callback API to promises.

```
$.when($.ajax(somefunction), someOtherPromise).then(function(result, other){
   // in here both promises have run to fulfillment and data is available
   // so place the rest of your code here
});
```